# Строковые операторы

Tags: javascript

Почему на JavaScript "11"<"3" дает результат true?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что это лексикографическое сравнение.

Вы видите в этих строках числа, а JS в данном случае только символы. Код символа '1' меньше, чем у символа '3' - поэтому true.

Answer (score 1):

Cравнение строк производится слева на право посимвольно, если код символа из первой строки больше кода символа из другой строки на этойже позиции, то первая строка больше. Если одна строка является продолжением другой, то первая больше второй (т.е. '51' < '511')